# Function can't see anything outside of itself (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I made classic interceptor for angular, and now I make an interceptor for syncfusion requests. I found a solution but I have a problem.
Why can't I call method in my function instance?
Here is my source code

[image: source]

```
import { DataManager, UrlAdaptor } from '@syncfusion/ej2-data';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AppGlobalService } from '../appglobal.service';

export class CustomAdaptor extends UrlAdaptor {
  router: Router;

  constructor(private AppGlobal: AppGlobalService) {
    super();
  }

  beforeSend(dm: DataManager, request: XMLHttpRequest) {
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    dm.dataSource.headers = [{ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.AppGlobal.GetCookie() }];

    request.onloadend = function () {
      if (request.status == 401) {
        this.goBack();
      }
    }
  }

  goBack() {
    this.router = this.AppGlobal.GetRouter();
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }
}
```

All I want to do is, if I have a 401 error, to go back to the login page, so it would be even better if I can directly call the login page without the goBack method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each function declaration has its own context to which by default `this` refers. To preserve the outer `this` you can replace *function* with *arrow function* .

```
request.onloadend = () => {
   if (request.status == 401) {
      this.goBack();
   }
}
```

Comment: Just what I was gonna say- this is the easy solution.